# Change ID of dynamically added divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm making a website where you can put your personal info and make a CV.
Now I want to make the part where you can put in the courses which you followed, but how can I add more fields dynamically and change the ID of the element (+1) so that you get naam_opleiding1, naam_opleiding2, with jQuery?

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" id="naam_opleiding" value="" placeholder="Naam opleiding"><br>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" id="naam_instituut" value="" placeholder="Naam instituut" /><br>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" id="startdatum" onfocus="(this.type='date')" value="" placeholder="Startdatum opleiding" /><br>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" id="einddatum" onfocus="(this.type='date')" value="" placeholder="Einddatum opleiding"/><br>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" id="overige_informatie"  value="" placeholder="Overige informatie"/><br>

        <button class="button add_field_button" id="opleiding_toevoegen" value="Opleiding toevoegen">Opleiding toevoegen</button>


$(wrapper).append('<div><br><br>' +
                    '<input class="input-field" name="mytext[]" type="text" id="naam_opleiding" value="" placeholder="Naam opleiding"><br>\n' +
                    '                        <input class="input-field" name="mytext[]" type="text" id="naam_instituut" value="" placeholder="Naam instituut" /><br>\n' +
                    '                        <input class="input-field" name="mytext[]" type="text" id="startdatum" value="" placeholder="Startdatum" /><br>\n' +
                    '                        <input class="input-field" name="mytext[]" type="text" id="einddatum" value="" placeholder="Einddatum"/><br>\n' +
                    '                        <input class="input-field" name="mytext[]" type="text" id="overige_informatie"  placeholder="Overige informatie"/><br>\n' +
                    '                        <a href="#" class="remove_field">Verwijder opleiding</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
            $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
        });
```

Comment: you can make a var tracking the current "id" and when appending a new input, just increase the current id, and set the id.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will let you add as many extra input as you want, for multiple input groups.

The input groups need to be wrapped in a div with a class `.input-wrapper`, with the attributes `placeholder` and `name` set, these are used to automatically create the input attributes (including a unique `id`).

The delete button always removes the last input that matches the selection pattern, that way when you save the information the indexes will be in sequence.

I've simplified the code a little for demo purposes, and commented it fully.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were hoping for

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to .add-input buttons
$(document).on("click", ".add-input", function() {

  // Move up DOM tree to nearest wrapper
  el = $(this).closest(".input-wrapper");

  // Store name and placeholder for group
  name = el.attr("name");
  placeholder = el.attr("placeholder");

  // Count number of existing inputs by checking which have an id that starts with wrapper name
  // Using name here, in addition to input, so that you could add other inputs into the group wrapper if needed
  // You may want to switch .children to .find if you want to add more wrappers
  count = el.children("input[id^=" + name + "]").length;

  // Add to index
  next = parseInt(count + 1);

  // Append input
  el.append("<input id='" + name + "-" + next + "' placeholder='" + placeholder + " " + next + "'>");


});

// Add click event to .add-input buttons
$(document).on("click", ".delete-input", function() {

  // Move up DOM tree to nearest wrapper to get name
  name = $(this).closest(".input-wrapper").attr("name");
  
  // Move up DOM tree to nearest wrapper and then find last input that matches pattern and delete it
  $(this).closest(".input-wrapper").children("input[id^=" + name + "]").last().remove();

});
```

```css
input,
label {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input name="email" placeholder="Email">

<div name="course" class="input-wrapper" placeholder="Course">

  <label>Courses</label>

  <button class="add-input">Add</button>
  <button class="delete-input">Delete</button>

  <input id='course-1' placeholder='Course 1'>
  <input id='course-2' placeholder='Course 2'>

</div>

<div name="qualification" class="input-wrapper" placeholder="Qualification">

  <label>Qualifications</label>

  <button class="add-input">Add</button>
  <button class="delete-input">Delete</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At this moment, I'm using jsPDF as a library and I have to make sure that I specified all of the fields with a certain ID. So how can I specify an increment of ID by 1 with this code?

Comment: Also added a delete button for each group, you'll likely need one I imagine

Comment: I made a mistake in the delete button so it was tempermental, have updated that so it is now fully working